# Creating line based on angle using MapInfo?

Tags: mapinfo

I have a point based object table (`Temp`) in which a column contains angles. Based on those angles, I want to create line (5mtr) in angle direction. My current table projection is WGS 84.

Is it possible in MapInfo?

[image]

Comment: Your western bearing angle is wrong -- 180+90 = 270, not 240. Note that the backangle from points shifted east or west, will not be exactly +/-90 due to curvature of the Earth.

Comment: Yes it is 270. My bad. And i agree that it will not be accurate as per my requirement. But if it is possible to create those line nearby angle direction?

Comment: Possible? Certainly. This only the Direct (aka Forward) [geodetic problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesy) after all, but it might be *obscenely* difficult, or a cakewalk, depending on the tools available in MapInfo.

Comment: I tried this query : update temp set obj = createline(centroidX(obj), centroidY(obj), centroidX(obj)*sin(angle), centroidY(obj)*cos(angle)). But i am not getting the desired result.

Comment: Nor should you, with that formula. Implementation of the iterative solution of the partial differential equation to solve the Direct problem isn't a comment topic. You need to do some more research on implementation alternatives, then update the question to contain what you have chosen, include your code, and describe the problem encountered. Then you need to wait for someone who groks both MapInfo and geodesy.

Comment: Thank you for your support. Will research more before asking this question.

Answer (score 1):

To get the end point coordinates, you have to add the distance to the end point to the start point's coordinates:

```
UPDATE temp SET obj = CreateLine(
    CentroidX(obj),
    CentroidY(obj),
    CentroidX(obj) + 5 * sin(angle),
    CentroidY(obj) + 5 * cos(angle))
```

This works only in a projection that uses meters as unit (in WGS84, you would get 5 degree lines).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `Offset()` function to calculate the new position based on the existing point, the angle and the distance:

```
UPDATE temp SET obj = CreateLine(
   CentroidX(obj),
   CentroidY(obj),
   CentroidX(Offset(obj, angle, 5, "m")),
   CentroidY(Offset(obj, angle, 5, "m")))
```

If you are working with projected data, you can consider using `CartesianOffset()` instead.

Also remember that MapInfo Pro calculates angles counter clock-wise using east as 0.